# Preventing Multiple Instance of Application/Activity When Opening Files

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have one activity which forms the basis of my application. Here is the problem.

- I create an activity instance called `Instance1`.
- My activity is then sent to the background by navigating back to the home menu. `onPause` and `onStop` are called on `Instance1`.
- I then navigate to `Gmail` and open an emails attachment.
- This creates a new instance of my activity 'Instance2` (I know this because I log what the instance is). Anything I do now within my activity is within this new instance.
- If I then navigate out and to gmail, `onDestroy` is called on `Instance2` then if I open my application by touching the icon the original `Instance1` `onRestart` is called.

Here is my intent filter inside my `manifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.dog" />
</intent-filter>
```

I have also added the following to my Applications tag in the manifest file but it has no effect.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

**Question**

Why can't it realise there is an instance running and open that?

**ADDITION**

I used singleInstance and moved it into my Activity tag. However, now I can't get my email attachments data? Previously I used the following.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent != null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity","Intent not null");
            Uri u = intent.getData();
            if (u != null) {
                Log.d("MainActivity","URI not null");
```

Comment: did you try single instance ?

Comment: have you tried   `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launchMode tag is part of the [`<activity>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) element, not the application element.

You should use singleTop to re-use the existing activity.

Comment: Ok `singleInstance` worked not `singleTop`. The problem is now the attachmet data isn't being received in my onRestart method when I go `getIntent.getData();`?

Comment: Does `onNewIntent` get called?

Comment: That does get called and the intent does get data. However now there is problems with permissions whilst reading gmail. I have added these permissions but still no joy. I hate android. You helped me solve my original problem and more. Thank you

Comment: Great stuff. Android lifecycle can be a little frustrating but it sounds like you're nearly there so don't give up! Try a new question if you don't figure out the permissions stuff.